# Git store credentials

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

git-credential-store is great for storing, but it seems it's not customized enough! I want to store credentials for specific branches, like for all branches except for master one, and/or for specific commands, like ex: store credentials for pull and fetch and don't store for push!

Comment: But that’s not how Git works, so why would you want to do that?!

Comment: @poke for safety ! I don't want to push to master easily, like I pushed a lot, I have many branches, multiple windows, I always has that fear, I just want a small validation for dealing with master branch, that's it!

Comment: Well, Git still doesn’t work that way.

Comment: @challenger You need to protect the remote branches you're talking about if you're pushing on `github` or `gitlab` for instance